# Replace wildcard from string

Tags: python, replace, wildcard

I have a script that is creating a variable like this:

```
ex = "/Volumes/Obelix/5215.tif, /Volumes/Gemeinsam/25.tif, /Volumes/Obelix/5100.tif"
```

Is it possible to remove everything with `/Volumes/Gemeinsam/*`, so I finally get:

```
ex = "/Volumes/Obelix/5215.tif, /Volumes/Obelix/5100.tif"
```

I'm not used to wildcards in Python so I have some problems. I've read a lot about `re.sub()`, but can't get it to work here.

Comment: Everything is possible if you just believe.

Comment: You could try a Regex.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What exactly does *"cant [sic] get it work here"* mean - where is the code, and what is the problem with it?

Comment: If you don't post code, then my only advice is to move the `Gameinsam` subfolder out of the main folder... there, done ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't really deal with wildcards. You should read more on Regex, which isn't Python specific.

In any case, this should take care of it:

```
ex = "/Volumes/Obelix/5215.tif, /Volumes/Gemeinsam/25.tif, /Volumes/Obelix/5100.tif"
newex = re.sub(r'/Volumes/Gemeinsam/.+?,?(\s|$)', '', ex)
```

Comment: I dont get what .+?,?(\s|$)  exactly means, but thats exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: The .+?,? tells it to match any filename that comes after the last slash, with or without the comma (the ,? isn't really necessary, actually, but it may help for clarity). The (\s|$) tells it to stop matching at space or end of string, so that it doesn't match everything after your first /Volumes/Gemeinsam/.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a bit of pre-parsing depending on how sure you are of the data, but you can use the in `in` operator to check if a string contains another string. Then, you can either use a loop or list comprehension depending on what is most readable.

```
ex = [x.strip() for x in "/Volumes/Obelix/5215.tif, /Volumes/Gemeinsam/25.tif, /Volumes/Obelix/5100.tif".split(',')]
check = "/Volumes/Gemeinsam"
new_ex = [x for x in ex if check not in x]
```

Comment: `strip` should not be necessary at all; use `split(', ')` to remove the whitespace. But maybe you should `join` it back together afterwards?

Comment: @tobias_k `split(",")` won't remove whitespace

Comment: @jonrsharpe Whops, right; thought he was using `split(', ')`